# 'six' vs 'sixer' in context of cricket

Tags: passive-voice

Basic Question: When to use "six", when to use "sixer"?

Which is correct/better in the following and why?
1. "The boy hit a six." or "The boy hit a sixer."
2. "A sixer was hit by the boy." or "A six was hit by the boy."

Comment: A 'sixer' is really schoolboy slang. The term is 'six'. You hit a six, or hit for a six. Either is acceptable, though the first refers more to the score & the second to the stroke, or to the return of the bowl.

Comment: A sixer is a term from Conkers rather than Cricket.  It would only be used in Cricket in a jocular manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it is better to use 'six' instead of 'sixer'. 'Sixer' is a kind of Indian English.

Check [OALD.](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sixer?q=sixer)

In PV also, "A six was hit by the boy" is preferable rather than "A sixer was hit by the boy."

Hope this will help.